How to mock private methods in when().thenReturn() statements in springbatch testing
There is a private method in a springBatch Beans. configuration class.
@Slf4j
public class EodDataDumpSpringBatchConfig {

private Resource getWriterResource(StepExecution stepExecution, Storage storage) {
        String chunkUri = stepExecution.getJobParameters().getString(EodDataDumpConstants.CHUNK_URI);
        String fileUri = chunkUri + stepExecution.getStepName();
        Resource resource = new GoogleStorageResource(storage, fileUri);
        return resource;
    }

....

}

I am writing a springBatchTest:
@SpringBatchTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringJUnitConfig({EodDataDumpSpringBatchConfig.class})
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.properties")
@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
public class EodDataDumpSpringBatchTest {

@Value("file:src/test/resources/storageFile.csv")
    private Resource resource;

@Test
    public void dataDumpJobEndToEndTest() throws Exception {
        
    }

}

I want to mock the private method in when().thenReturn statement.
What I mean is, when any method calls that private method it should get a mocked Resource.
I tried:

ReflectionUtils
PoweMockit


Consider instead of mocking a private method (which indeed could be really difficult) you could create a factory or similar to create the resource object:
@Slf4j
public class EodDataDumpSpringBatchConfig {
    
    // Set it via Setter or Constructor
    private GoogleStorageResourceFactory factory;

    private Resource getWriterResource(StepExecution stepExecution, Storage storage) {
        return factory.createGoogleStorageResource(stepExecution, storage);
    }
}

/*visibility-as-you-wish*/ class GoogleStorageResourceFactory {
    public Resource createGoogleStorageResource(StepExecution stepExecution, Storage storage) {
        String chunkUri = stepExecution.getJobParameters().getString(EodDataDumpConstants.CHUNK_URI);
        String fileUri = chunkUri + stepExecution.getStepName();
        return new GoogleStorageResource(storage, fileUri);
    }

}

This new type could easily be mocked during testing and could also be tested separately.

If your method is private, then it needs to be tested from the piece of code which is calling this private method and has access to it. This is the intuition that you should go forward with for writing unit tests. Otherwise this question doesn't make sense, since private methods cant be unit tested. Yes you can come up with a complicated piece of code (using reflection api) which any developer irrespective of experience would need some time to understand and that defeats the purpose of writing understandable code.
If you are fixated on viewing this method as a unit and write unit tests (focus on the intuition) then you should change the access modifier for this method (use public). This will result in a better maintainable code and will go along the intuition of unit testing.

You can use Mockito to mock your function.
var eodDataDumpSpringBatchConfig = mock(EodDataDumpSpringBatchConfig.class);
when(eodDataDumpSpringBatchConfig.getWriterResource(any(), any()).thenReturn(resource);

Re private function, you cannot mock a private function, you can change it to package private and then you will be able to mock it.
Check out this answer.
Note that the package should be the same package in your tests class as in your application, e.g:
src
├── main
│   └── java
│       └── util
│           └── SomeClass
└── test
    └── java
        └── util
            └── SomeClassTests


How Can I mock package private method?? I tried that also, but getting errors. Can you please help
